# About $ A^{-1}$ where A is 10x10 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be 10x10 invertible matrix with real entries s.t sum of each row is 1. Then which of follwing is true:

1. Sum of entries of each row of inverse of A is 1.
2. Sum if entriez of each column of inverse of A is 1.
3. Trace of  inverse of A is non zero.

I tried by assuming A to be 10x10 indentity matrix. But if we take this, then all options 1,2,3 are true. But answer in only 1.what other way is there?

Comment: Hint: The restriction to $10 \times 10$ matrices is inessential. So, what happens for $2 \times 2$ matrices?

Comment: Randomly taken 2x2 matrix removes option 2, but still 3 option holds

Comment: Let $M$ be the matrix with all entries $1$. Note that $A$ satisfies $AM=M$. Now $M=A^{-1}AM=A^{-1}M$. What does it tell you?

Comment: $A$ is invertible. How can it be nilpotent?

Answer (score 0):

1 is the only one that is always true!
It is easy to find a counterexample to 2, and for 3, you can use the block diagonal self inverse matrix with 5 diagonal blocks the type:
\begin{align*}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\end{align*}
And finally to answer why 1 is true, try looking at the vector $j = (1,1,\dots,1)^T$.

> $Mj = j$, and thus $j=M^{-1}Mj = M^{-1}j$.